# Remove particular dynamic div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `append` to append some `input` data with `div`. After some appending, I have data as below :

```
<div id="holder">
</div>
```

```js
var data = "<div id=1><input type='text' id='test_1' name='test_1'></div><div id=2><input type='text' id='test_2' name='test_2'></div>"
$("#holder").append(data );
```

I am appending data using `append`. Now, I want to remove particular `div` based on id.
For i.e. if id is 1 then remove this row. `<div id=1><input type='text' id='test_1' name='test_1'></div>` and like that for all.
I tried `$("#holder").remove()`, but it will remove all data. I want to remove particular `div` then what to do ?

Comment: `$('#1').remove();` ... ?

Comment: You should seriously read about `selectors` before working with both `CSS` and `jQuery`. To select an element by its `id` is the most trivial thing here.

Comment: @JeetenParmar how do you determine which div needs to be removed? It's a simple task, you just need to figure out how to get the selector for the relevant element.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, i will get id based on user click. So, I will have id for sure. now, i want to remove `<div id=1>` to `</div>` if id is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes `$("#holder").remove()` will remove everything because this is the parent div consisting of all child divs(like div id=1)

Its a bad practice to give as numericals like the way you are doing(id=1,id=2 etc)

Append some alphabets along with number like id=a1,id=a2....

to remove a particular div

try

```
$("#a1").remove()
```

from the comments above you have said that you will get the `id` from `click`

so try like below

```
$(selector).click(function(){
var id=//get the id of the div
$("#a"+id).remove()
});
```

Comment: I din't know that i can also delete it that way. I thought I need to use `holder` to delete data.

Comment: @JeetenParmar once upon a time I was like you(ask a question and get tons of downvotes) but stackoverflow made to answer and questions and get tons of upvotes

Comment: great to hear positive from you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

```
var theId = document.getElementById("1");
theID.remove();
```